# Exchange message Header formatting

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to set exchange message header. I need Help In formatting the code. I need to set below values in header

```
usr.Person.Name = "Peter"
usr.Person.ID = "ABC123"
```

I tried

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("usr.Person.Name", "Peter");
exchange.getIn().setHeader("usr.Person.ID", "ABC123");
```

But when I see in Active MQ it is formatted as

```
usr_DOT_Person_DOT_Name: Peter
usr_DOT_Person_DOT_ID : ABC123
```

I need to print as it is, I tried to google is but no luck. Any suggestions??

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify what wasn't addressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a violation of the JMS specification to use a `.` character in the name of a message header/property which is why the Camel JMS component translates it to `DOT` as noted in [the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_message_header_mapping). You can always translate it back into the original format when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

From Camel in action

> In Camel, a header can be named anything that will fit in a Java
>   String, and its value can be any Java object. This presents a few
>   problems when sending to and receiving from JMS destinations.
>
> ... 
>   Any
>   period (.) characters are replaced by *DOT*, and any hyphens (-) are
>   replaced with *HYPHEN*. For example, a header named
>   org.apache.camel.Test-Header would be converted to
>   org_DOT_apache_DOT_camel_DOT_Test_HYPHEN_Header before being sent to a
>   JMS destination. If this message is consumed by a Camel route at some
>   point down the line, the header name will be converted back.

Also you can find this info here https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html in MESSAGE HEADER MAPPING section.